# Django Apache 2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy my django application on apache2, I am on an AWS ec2 ubuntu instance. Originally I got an Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding, so I switched my python from 2.7 to 3.6 by removing my env and starting a new virtual env on 3.6, I also purged python 2.7 and 3.7 from my instance. After that I got a no module named 'Django error' in my apache. Any help is appreciated been stuck on a while with this :).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/myproj
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Alias /static /home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/myproj/static
<Directory /home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/myproj/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/myproj/myproj>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess myproj python-path=/home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/myproj python-home=/home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/venv2

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/myproj/myproj/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Also when I run pip3 install django my django is in
Requirement already satisfied: django in /home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.2.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make my website run through apache by changing to python 3.6 by creating a new virtual environment with python 3.6 reinstalling the requirments, and then I uninstall libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 using sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3, and then I installed it again within my python 3.6 virtual environment and then the website ended up working.

Answer (score 1):

Once you configured your EC2 instance, I will assume you want backend and frontend in this server, the access to the instance via `shell`. Then run:

To update packages from Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Python with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Install `pip` with:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Then you need to install a virtual environment, you can use `virtualenv`:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Create a virtual env with:

```
virtualenv mynewvenv
```

Then get into the venv with:

```
source mynewvnev/bin/activate
```

Once you are inside your vnev, run this to install Django:

```
pip install django
```

Then I recommend uploading your Django project into GitHub or GitLab, then clone that repository.

Is very important to update your `settings.py`, especially the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` if you are redirecting with a custom domain:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['yourdomain.com',
                 'www.yourdomain.com',]
```

Also is very important to update your DB access if required, in case you are running DB with default `sqlite3` just make sure that the DB name, user, and password match with your actual info.

If you did the above correctly, then try to update the `WSGI` section on your Apache `config` file to look something like this:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess yourapp python-home=/usr/local/venvs/yourapp
WSGIProcessGroup DjangoMainAppName
```

It is likely that the error is on this line:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess delta_new python-path=/home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/myproj python-home=/home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/venv2
```

Try changing to:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess delta_new python-path=/home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/myproj python-home=/home/ubuntu/pydjangoenv/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Using the accurate Python version.

You can read on how to properly configure the `config` file for a Django app with daemon mode for a single app [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#daemon-mode-single-application).

Comment: Yea after I made the changes I am back to the original error:  Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Comment: Try running commands: `unset PYTHONHOME` and `unset PYTHONPATH`